# Building hadoop keeps failing, even though protoc 2.5.0 is set on my system

Tags: hadoop, protoc

I am now trying to build hadoop using mvn after I finished its prerequisites.
However, I get this message even though I have right version of protoc.
I tried to rebuild protoc 2.5.0 several times already and every time all the tests of it would be passed and build successfully. I don't know why this keeps happening, Please help. Thanks.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:protoc
>   (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common:
>   `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException`: protoc failure ->
>   [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors,
>   re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X
>   switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more
>   information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the
>   following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the
>   build with the command [ERROR]   `mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common`

TJ@DESKTOP-6940Q5M /cygdrive/e/hdc
$ `protoc --version`
libprotoc 2.5.0

Thanks for the advice that I missed to upload the display on the re-run with -e switch. Here it is.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc failure
        at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.protoc.ProtocMojo.execute(ProtocMojo.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: protoc failure
        at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.protoc.ProtocMojo.execute(ProtocMojo.java:102)
        ... 22 more

I really don't know what its problem is since I am a starter with hadoop. 
Please help.

Comment: So, what is the actual error? Apart from "protoc failure" there are no meaningful messages. Could you try running maven with those -e and -X switches to get more info?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have debugged with -e switch again and got the result like I have added to my post. I have no idea what the problems is. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The hadoop maven protobuf compiler is, sadly, useless when there's an error.

This could just be some error in the `.protoc` files which isn't being reported as such, instead mvn is just failing without showing the root cause.

I end up debugging compilation problems by using the protoc command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to install `protobuf-compiler`. Then build hadoop-maven-plugins. The go back to hadoop source code parent directory and execute maven goal

```
cd <hadoop_source_path>
sudo yum install protobuf-compiler
cd hadoop-maven-plugins
mvn install
cd ..
mvn package -skipTests
```

This worked for me.